# Django : How to pass custom value to inline css

Tags: django, django-inlinecss

I am writing to pass custom values to the inline css , but i am unable to get this since i am very new to django framework .

Thanks in Advance

```
   <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: {{news_curr_idx}}" aria-valuenow="25" arwiria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{news_curr_idx}}</div>
</div>
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def tutorial(request):
start = datetime.datetime.now()
news_curr_idx = request.user.profile.news_curr_idx

if news_curr_idx == TOTAL_QUESTION:
    return redirect('end_experiment')

assigned_chunk_to_user(request.user.profile)
news_curr = NewsItem.objects.all().filter(
    chunk_id=request.user.profile.assigned_chunk_idx)[news_curr_idx]

context = {
    'newsItem': news_curr,
    'news_curr_idx': news_curr_idx + 1,
    'total_question': TOTAL_QUESTION

}

if request.method == 'POST':
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    user_annot_form = TutorialAnnotationForm(request.POST, newsItem=news_curr, author=request.user.profile,
                                             elapsed_time=elapsed_time.microseconds)

    if request.POST.get("action_name") == 'ISSUE':
        assert not UserAnnotation.objects.filter(
            author=request.user.profile).filter(newsItem=news_curr).values()
        return redirect('report_issue')

    if user_annot_form.is_valid():
        if request.POST.get("action_name") == 'NEXT':
            user_annot_form.save()
            request.user.profile.news_curr_idx += 1
            request.user.profile.save()
            assert UserAnnotation.objects.filter(
```

author=request.user.profile).filter(newsItem=news_curr).values()
return redirect('tutorial')
else:
# TODO add logger
print(user_annot_form.errors.as_json())

```
return render(request, 'annotating/tutorial.html', context)
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is the output?

Comment: It also would be helpful if you post the corresponding view

Comment: i have added the view code you can check

Comment: Error it shows is property value expected , at-rule or selector value expected @IainShelvington

Comment: What error? Do you have a traceback and error message you can add to the question?

Comment: No , i was able to solve the issue there was some mistake in the format of writing .